# How to make a bot that when commanded sends the number of members which belong to a specific role (Using role id)?

Tags: discord.js

Pls use role id. Here's my codeline :

```
client.on('message', message =>{

let roleID = "786148346846117940";
let memberCount = message.guild.roles.cache.get('roleID').members.size;
 console.log(memberCount)   
});
```

I tried this code but somehow even when 1 member has the role it send me:

```
0
0
```

But when i am the person who has the role then i get:

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a `String` instead of the variable `roleID` to Collection#get. So instead of `786148346846117940`, it is `roleID`.

---

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("786148346846117940");

    console.log(Role ? `Role ${Role.name} has ${Role.members.size} members.` : `The role doesn't exist.`);
});
```

Comment: Thank You so much it worked perfectly fine